# How do I make a Button not have padding?

Tags: android, android-button

Basically, I want the white button view not to have that grey padding, while retaining the button properties, so the click can be visible. This is my xml code below, I already tried adding a shape as the background but that removes the click animation that I want, I also tried just having a TextView with a TouchListener to create an animation but I was told that that is not good practice because of accessibility:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/alertBackground">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/alertTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="?attr/colorOnPrimary"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/alertMessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:ems="12"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/alert_message_incorrect_password"
            android:textColor="?attr/colorOnPrimary"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/alertTitle" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/alertButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/alertBackground"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/alertButton2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/separator" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/alertButton2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/alertBackground"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/separator"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/alertButton" />


        <View
            android:id="@+id/separator"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@color/separator_grey"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/alertButton"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/alertMessage" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Comment: send us what you did

Comment: show your xml first

Comment: @ebs237 added the xml

Comment: use `android:insetTop="0dp"
            android:insetBottom="0dp"
            android:insetLeft="0dp"
            android:insetRight="0dp"` it should solve the problem

Comment: @ebs237 it stays the same

Answer (score 0):

You can set minWidth, minHeight, insetTop, insetBottom by zero.
So like this.

```
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:insetTop="0dp"
        android:insetBottom="0dp" />
```

Comment: it stayed the same

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the style if used any.
2. Mark the width and height as match constraints.

Comment: answer should be well explained with code!

Answer (score 0):

you can create custom drawable and use them as background in button ...

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <solid android:color="#4CAF50"/>

</shape>
```

and apply in button

```
android:background="@drawable/yourcustomview"
```

Comment: I already tried that, it works but it loses some of the buttons properties like the click animation

Comment: fo animation & effect I think you have to use the material button please visit -  https://material.io/components/buttons/android